# Having trouble outputting to a CSV file. I know the output is a curly brackets "collection", but I'm stumped

Tags: powershell, collections, powerbi

I have a small PowerShell script that outputs two columns:

- A string labeled Name and
- a collection (in curly braces) labeled Users

I need to output this to a CSV file, but the collection just outputs as error-gobbledygook.

I know I need to convert this to a string or iterate or something, but I am having trouble figuring this out.

```bsh
$ActiveSharedCapacityWorkspaces = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Scope Organization -All | Where {($_.IsOnDedicatedCapacity -eq $false) -and ($_.State -eq "Active") -and ($_.Type -ne "PersonalGroup")}

$ActiveSharedCapacityWorkspaceUsers = $ActiveSharedCapacityWorkspaces | Select Name,Users | Get-Unique -AsString

$ExportFile = "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\ActiveSharedCapacityWorkspaceUsers.csv"

$ActiveSharedCapacityWorkspaceUsers | Export-Csv $ExportFile
```

Expected Result:

```
Name:WorkspaceName            Users:Joe Schmoe, Billy Bob
```

Actual Results:

```
Name:WorkspaceName               Users:System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.Models.GroupUserAccessRight,Microsoft.PowerBI.Common.Api.Workspaces.WorkspaceUser]
```

Comment: You should add the `-NoTypeInformation` flag to your `Export-Csv` command.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data that has the braces.

Comment: Aside from @AdminOfThings hint,  use a calculated property to join users `$ActiveSharedCapacityWorkspaceUsers = $ActiveSharedCapacityWorkspaces | Select-Object Name,@{n="Users';e={$_.Users -join ', '}}`

Comment: Sample of data that has braces:
{JoeBlow@xxx.onmicrosoft.com, BillyBob@xxx.onmicrosoft.com, ZekeCornelius@xxx.onmicrosoft.com, JoeSchmoe@xxx.onmicrosoft.com}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Get-PowerBiWorkspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.workspaces/get-powerbiworkspace?view=powerbi-ps#outputs) returns an `IEnumerable`, in your case you're storing a Linq expression on this `IEnumerable`.

As stated by @LotPings you've to invoke the `Where`-Linq expression. This is done by enumeration operations, like `-join` (because the join operator has to enumerate the collection, which causes the Linq query to be resolved/invoked). As @LotOfPings and @AdminOfThings suggested change your code to:

```
$ActiveSharedCapacityWorkspaces = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Scope Organization -All | Where {($_.IsOnDedicatedCapacity -eq $false) -and ($_.State -eq "Active") -and ($_.Type -ne "PersonalGroup")}

$ActiveSharedCapacityWorkspaceUsers = $ActiveSharedCapacityWorkspaces | Select-Object Name,@{n="Users';e={$_.Users.UserPrincipalName -join ', '}}

$ExportFile = "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\ActiveSharedCapacityWorkspaceUsers.csv"

$ActiveSharedCapacityWorkspaceUsers | Export-Csv $ExportFile -NoTypeInformation
```

The [-NoTypeInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6) suppresses type information in the 0th line of the generated CSV file. If you're PowerShell 6 type information generation is deactivated per default.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone.  I am using PowerShell 5.1 BTW.  Now, I don't get the same error in that CSV Cell, but I still don't get the Workspace Usernames.  Using the code above, I get output like: "Microsoft.PowerBI.Common.Api.Workspaces.WorkspaceUser,Microsoft.PowerBI.Common.Api.Workspaces.WorkspaceUser,Microsoft.PowerBI.Common.Api.Workspaces.WorkspaceUser" for the User field.

Comment: @WillHoward can you retest above code. I think you've to select the `UserPrincipalName`. `$_.Users` changed to `$_.Users.UserPrincipalName`. The reason is that [WorkspaceUser](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-powershell/blob/7c87a3cb4e8678df5c50b024ed1a62a2714062cd/src/Common/Common.Api/Workspaces/WorkspaceUser.cs) doesn't have a `ToString()` implementation.